ESP32 / WROOM - Micropython Ver. 1.22 issue
i have a working ESP32 project, the project started 2022, with Micropython Ver1.18. the project fetches the web to get the current location and the correct time and the correct time zone according to the location. (code listed below)
def getLocation():

    global lng,lat,acu,udf

    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

    locationStr = "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=" + APIKey

    try:
        response = urequests.post(locationStr, headers=headers, data=ujson.dumps(data))
        location = ujson.loads(response.content)
        lng = location["location"]["lng"]
        lat = location["location"]["lat"]
        acu = location["accuracy"]
        print ("the current Location is lat %s, Log %s with accuracy %s" % (lat,lng,acu))
        response.close()
    except:
        print("unable to read the current location %s" %OSError)

Both Micropython versions downloaded from here https://micropython.org/download/ESP32_GENERIC/
and i am using OS windows 11 with a programing editor Thonny 4.1.4
As mentioned earlier, the program is working fine since 2022. i decide to upgrade the program to Micropython Ver 1.22.2 After updating the MicroPython to the new release. the program Breaks down with Memory Error 16 at "urequest.post" command. when I change the "https" to "http" in locationStr variable, the program doesn't break but return an error saying the server support https only.
is anyone faced this or has an explanation?
thanks in advance
I tried to reduce the program to the min size but i didn't succussed

https is a memory intensive operation (compared to http). It is possible that the newer version of micropython occupies more memory, leaving less for your code, and the result is that you're running out of memory.
There are a variety of ways of reducing the memory footprint of your install:

removing modules that are included in the firmware by default
precompiling your code into a .mpy file

The documentation covers some of these options under Optimizations and MicroPython manifest files.
